# Отобрать в папке файлы по индексам

Tags: python, циклы, for

Я пользуюсь функцией glob.iglob для работы с папками. В папке много файлов, картинок, далее я работаю с ними при помощи opencv. Их можно просто перебрать при помощи цикла, но теперь мне нужно обратиться не ко всем файлам из директории, их слишком много, а к определенным. Я знаю индексы интересующих меня файлов.

```
for n in glob.iglob('menus\*'):
    template = cv2.imread(n)

my_indexes = [2,3,5]
```

glob.iglob - тип - generator object и он, по-моему не итерируется, при попытке записи glob.iglob('menus*')[1] - выдает ошибку

```
'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Генератор и итератор - разные вещи. Генераторы не итерируются, а, как видно из названия, генерируют значение на основании исходного значения и формулы получения следующего. Для вызова следующего значения генератора, генерируемого методом `yeild`, используется метод `next`. Либо необходимо в явном виде "вытянуть" итерируемый объект из генератора, как показано в примере ниже (`enumerate`).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,name in enumerate(glob.iglob('menus\*')):
  if i in my_indexes:
    template = cv2.imread(name)
```

см. [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

**Примечание**: можно сделать эффективней избавившись от `in`.